# Add protocol to wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, skype

I am trying to place `<a href="skype:sitspak?call">` in the footer of my WordPress installation.

In order to achieve that, I am adding `skype` protocol to `wp_allowed`.

Following, is the piece of code from **`functions.php`**

```
function wp_allowed_protocols() {
    static $protocols = array();

    if ( empty( $protocols ) ) {
        $protocols = array( 'http', 'https', 'ftp', 'ftps', 'mailto', 'news', 'irc', 'gopher', 'nntp', 'feed', 'telnet', 'mms', 'rtsp', 'svn', 'tel', 'fax', 'xmpp', 'webcal' );

        /**
         * Filters the list of protocols allowed in HTML attributes.
         *
         * @since 3.0.0
         *
         * @param array $protocols Array of allowed protocols e.g. 'http', 'ftp', 'tel', and more.
         */
        $protocols = apply_filters( 'kses_allowed_protocols', $protocols );
    }

    return $protocols;
```

I am placing following code in my child theme's **`function.php`**

```
//
// Your code goes below
//

function ss_allow_skype_protocol( $protocols ){
    array_push($protocols, 'skype');
    return $protocols;
}
add_filter( 'kses_allowed_protocols' , 'ss_allow_skype_protocol' );
```

But for some reason this doesn't work; how can I successfully achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Did you place the first piece of code into your functions.php? You only need the filter call (the 2nd block of code) and everything should work fine.

Comment: First piece is in wp-included/functions.php

Comment: Second piece is in child theme's functions.php

Comment: I haven't modified the core `functions.php` since it it not recommended way to do it.